# How to configure apache virtual hosts for a development machine?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup a dev version and a staging version of my php web app on a Ubuntu Linux 6.06.1 machine with Apache 2.0.55

I have my virtual hosts setup like so via webmin, but i always end up at the dev site and never stage when I try to browse to stage.sidev

```
Defines the default settings for all other virtual servers, and processes any unhandled requests.
Address Any
Port Any    Server Name sidev
Document Root Automatic

Virtual Server  Handles the name-based server dev.sidev on address 192.168.110.9.
Address 192.168.110.9
Port 80     Server Name dev.sidev
Document Root /var/www/dev

Virtual Server  Handles the name-based server sidev-svn on address *.
Address Any
Port 443    Server Name sidev-svn
Document Root Default

Virtual Server  Handles the name-based server stage.nplusidev on address 192.168.110.9.
Address 192.168.110.9
Port 80     Server Name stage.sidev
Document Root /home/admin/www/stage
```

I am connecting from windows xp with my hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.local
192.168.110.9       sidev
192.168.110.9   stage.sidev
192.168.110.9   dev.sidev
```

How am I supposed to configure my virtual hosts for this to work?

Comment: Are the lines starting with "Virtual Server" meant to be comment lines with a # in front of them? Also presumably you have these inside <VirtualHost> sections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive to tell Apache to distinguish between sites based on name - see [Name based virtual host support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) for a thorough explanation. (That will also guide you through checking that the `<VirtualHost>` directives not seen above are correct etc)